# How do I pass value from PostgreSQL trigger in a Python API call?

Tags: python, postgresql, triggers

Is there a way to access a value passed by a PostgreSQL trigger in a Python API call? How do I access such a value in the Python  API code?

Comment: What do you mean by "a value passed by a PostgreSQL trigger"?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe in other words , can a postgresql trigger return a value to an API call other than NEW or NULL  which the API call can access in its python code?

Comment: Ah, I get you. No, the only way for a trigger to communicate with the outside directly is via `NEW`. Of course it can have side effects and store stuff in the database, like a temporary table. The question is who is the recipient of the information, since the environment for a trigger is a DML statement.